# How to check auth login 3 table laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, eloquent

i have a auth login that i make, which have 3 table to auth as admin, how can i fix this? thx

```
public function postlogin(Request $request)
{
$admin = DB::table('M_ADMIN')->select(['M_ADMIN.PERNR'])->get();
$user  = DB::table('M_HEAD_SALLARY')
        ->join('M_USER', 'M_USER.PERNR', '=', 'M_HEAD_SALLARY.PERNR')
        ->where('M_USER.PERNR','LIKE','%'.$admin.'%') 
        ->where('M_HEAD_SALLARY.USRID_LONG',strtoupper($request->USRID_LONG))
        ->where('M_USER.PASS',$request->PASS)
        ->first();
    return redirect('/login');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **LoginController**, you can overwrite the attemptLogin method as follow

```
public function attemptLogin(Request $request) {
    $user = Admin::whereHas('M_HEAD_SALLARY', function($query){
        // condition
    })->whereHas('M_USER', function($query) {
     // condition
    });

    if (Auth::login($user)) {

        // Authentication passed...
    }
}
```